# jQuery - Hide Fixed Element After Scrolling Past Another

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, scroll

Basicly I want to hide a fixed element after it passes by another one and I was not able to figure it out how to.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test 1</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){ 

    var startOn = 5;
     var mc = $('#main_content').offset().top;
     var rc = $('#related_content').offset().top;
     var om = $('#openmodal').offset().top;

    var rangeLimit = rc - om;

    $(window).scroll(function() {


         var wscroll = $(this).scrollTop();

        $('#openmodal').text('Y:' + wscroll);

        if (wscroll <= rangeLimit && wscroll > startOn ) {

            $('#openmodal').fadeIn(100);


        } else {

            $('#openmodal').fadeOut(100);

        }
    });

});
</script>
<style type="text/css">

    body { 
        background-color: #fff; 
    }

    div { 
       height: 1400px; /* For testing purposes only! It will vary afterwords. */
       border-top: 1px dotted black; 
       padding: 50px; 
       margin: 20px 20px 40px; 
       background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }

    div#wrapper { height: auto; border: none; background-color: #fff;}

    #openmodal {
            position: fixed;
            background-color: #0F5F01;
            cursor: pointer;
            bottom: 20px;
            left: 6px;
            width:60px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 27px;
            padding: 0;
            display: none;
            z-index: 999;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<h1>My Website!</h1>

    <div id="main_content">
     <h2>This is my main content.</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="openmodal"></div>

    <div id="related_content">
     <h3>And this is my related content.</h3>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So my idea is to keep #openmodal visible until the scroll passes the #related_content div and it seems I can't get it working. All DIV's would have variable heights (except #openmodal), I've just set heights here for testing proposes.

Any idea how to archive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've finally figure it out!

So basically I cannot get an hidden element position, and I have to use position() instead of offset().

Here is what I've ended up with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test 1</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function() {


     var startOn = 5;
     var rc = $('#related_content').position().top;
     var om = $('#openmodal').position().top;
     $('#openmodal').hide();

    var rangeLimit = rc - om; 

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var wscroll = $(this).scrollTop();

        $('#openmodal').text('Y:' + wscroll);

        if ( wscroll <= rangeLimit && wscroll > startOn ) {

            $('#openmodal').fadeIn(500);


        } else {

            $('#openmodal').fadeOut(500);

        }
    });

});
</script>
<style type="text/css">

    body { 
        background-color: #fff; 
    }

    div { 
       height: 1400px; /* For testing purposes only! It will vary afterwords. */
       border-top: 1px dotted black; 
       padding: 50px; 
       margin: 20px 20px 40px; 
       background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }

    div#wrapper { height: auto; border: none; background-color: #fff;}

    #openmodal {
            position: fixed;
            background-color: #0F5F01;
            cursor: pointer;
            bottom: 20px;
            left: 6px;
            width:60px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 27px;
            padding: 0;
            z-index: 999;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<h1>My Website!</h1>

    <div id="main_content">
     <h2>This is my main content.</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="openmodal"></div>

    <div id="related_content">
     <h3>And this is my related content.</h3>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var startOn = 5;
var mc = $('#main_content').offset().top;
var rc = $('#related_content').offset().top;
var om = $('#openmodal').offset().top;

var rangeLimit = rc - om;
```

You are declaring these outside of scroll function, so they always have the initial value they get at the load of the page. You need to put them into the function that handles your scroll event.